# Having trouble deserializing with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to Deserialize something using JSON.NET. Here is json1.json file:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/fxbaeehYFMlvKKyJj6WLneDJn3o\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-09-16T18:49:25.000Z",
    "title": "New_Title_1"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is the C# i have written: (using Newtonsoft.Json;)

```
public class Snippet
{
    public string publishedAt { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    var json = webClient.DownloadString("c:\\users\\User\\documents\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\json1.json");
                    Response.Write(json + "<br />");

                    Item a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);
                    Response.Write(a.etag + " ----- <br />");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This solution will build fine but a.etag prints nothing. Where am I going wrong? Also: How would I deserialize publishedAt and title as they are nested in lists(?)

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>` -> `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>`...

Comment: In addition to @CodeCaster, `a.items[0].etag`

Answer (score 3):

You are not deserializing an `Item` but a `RootObject`

```
RootObject a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
Response.Write(a.items[0].etag + " ----- <br />");
```

If you expect your `List` to have multiple entries

```
RootObject a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach (Item item in a.items)
{
    Response.Write(item.etag + " ----- <br />");
}
```

If you want to make only one call

```
RootObject a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Item item in a.items)
{
    sb.Append(item.etag);
    sb.AppendLine(" ----- <br />");
}

Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

-- EDIT

About your "Also: How would I deserialize publishedAt and title as they are nested in lists?":

You don't have to do anything else as long as your classes stick to the JSON data format. They will be deserialized when deserializing your `RootObject`.

You can access it just like you access all properties

```
string title = a.items[0].snippet.title;
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way how to troubleshoot your JSON is to have it serialized by JSON.Net in a first place and **then you can compare the result of your class structure (and make proper changes to it)**.

1. Create an instance of RootObject and fill in all the properties (including the List)
2. Serialize it by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);`
3. Compare the string result to your json1.json file

Example of usage:

```
var rootObject = new RootObject
{
    items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item
        {
            etag = "123etag"
        }
    }
};
rootObject.items.FirstOrDefault().etag;
```

Comment: _"The best way how to troubleshoot your JSON is to have it serialized by JSON.Net in a first place"_ - that makes no sense. You generally deserialize JSON strings that you obtain from external sources. Sure, you can make it work by serializing something yourself that works, but that code still won't work on the JSON that you actually want to consume.

Comment: If you take a JSON from an external source and JSON.Net cannot deserialize it there is problem with a structure you are serializing it into. If you serialize a test object you can see what JSON correspond to your class structure and you can do appropriate changes. @CodeCaster

Comment: Both the structure (i.e classes) and JSON are well written here.The OP just doesn't use the good class to deserialize his data. Your solution won't help him at all in this case, because there is no way he can figure it out just looking at another piece of JSON data. I didn't downvote you anyway.